# Generate related lists of random number with constraints

Tags: python-2.7, random

I have the following code to generate some random numbers:

```
import random
random.seed(1)

lambdaj = []
tauj = []

for i in range(30):
    lambdaj.append(random.randint(2, 15))
    tauj.append(random.uniform(10/365, 40/365))

#What I want is:

for i in range(len(tauj)):
    if lambdaj[i]*tauj[i] >= 1:
        #RECALCULATE lambdaj and tauj by increasing the random.seed by 1
```

So, what I want to do is I want to have some lists of `lambdaj` and `tauj`, however, I do not want **related** `lambdaj[i]*tau[j] >= 1`. They should all be `< 1`. So, I think, I will need to increment on my seed and let it find some seed value that satisfies my requirement. However, I couldn't come up with a working for loop that does it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question implies that *any* lambda multiplied by *any* tau must be less than 1 (`i * j`), but your test implies that actually you only care about related lambdas and taus (`i * i`):

```
lambdaj[i] * tauj[j]   (In words)
lambdaj[i] * tauj[i]   (Your code test)
```

Assuming your code is what you meant, then there's no need to find a good seed: just regenerate the "bad" index:

```
for i in range(len(tauj)):
    while lambdaj[i] * tauj[i] >= 1:
        lambdaj[i] = random.randint(2, 15)
        tauj[i] = random.uniform(10/365, 40/365)
```

Alternatively, just do this while generating your data:

```
for i in range(30):
    l = j = 5   # something larger than 1
    while l * j >= 1:
        l = random.randint(2, 15)
        j = random.uniform(10/365, 40/365)
    lambdaj.append( l )
    tauj.append( j )
```

And indeed, if you're looking for actually random data, then don't ever set your seed.  With this method, and by not setting the seed (e.g., `.seed(1)`), your constraint is guaranteed *and* your data will be random for every script invocation.

Comment: I believe the answer is still on target.

Comment: The second alternative worked fine. However, the first one didn't work even though I tried it in different ways. Still, thank you very much; you definitely solved my problem.